# SQL-Server 2008 on a windows vista doesn't start

Tags: windows-vista, services, sql-server-2008

i have installed a SQL2008 Server developer-Edition on my Dell Precision M90 Notebook with windows Vista, but the service dosen't start.
SQL Server Configuration Manager shows MSSQLSERVER as stopped and an attempt to start this service fails. No entry in eventviewer... where to look?
What might be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where to look?

The Log directory for sql.

On my machine this is located in

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG

Also you sometimes get more details if you open a command prompt (as Administrator) and try to start the service using the syntax   Net Start ServiceName

Comment: Interactive start on a command prompt shows at least the following:
2010-03-27 20:59:58.06 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library coul
d not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Erro
r: 0x54b, state: 3. Failure to register an SPN may cause integrated authenticati
on to fall back to NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. F
urther action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authent
ication policies.

Comment: I think this is just a warning, which I think can be avoided by starting the server as LocalSystem.

Do you get messages like 'The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service is starting' and 'The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service was started successfully?

Comment: That is the issue, no other message than this 'Server Principal Name' - thing. The SQL-Server Log shows in detail how sql-server is starting, looks like ever but at the end there is the posted message. As the sql-server is configured not to accept sql-login there is no chance to work with it. This is a Show-Stopper.